# Sending another embed after deleting embed not working

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

That title made no sense but I'll clarify here. I have this command where it'll send an embed and get data from a JSON and then send it back inside of the embed and I want to make it so that after 5 seconds, it deletes and sends another JSON.

Here's the code:

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
  with open('test.json', 'r') as homeworkfile:
    homework = json.loads(homeworkfile.read())
  embed=discord.Embed(title='Test', description=f"Here's the saved contents for test: {homework}", color=0x9932CC)
  deletewarn=discord.Embed(title='Answer ticket expired.', description="Oops, looks like this ticket expired. Try saying !ss again?", color=0x9932CC)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=5)
  time.sleep(5)
  await ctx.send(embed=deletewarn)
```

When I use the command, it does send the other embed after 5 seconds have passed, but the other embed doesn't delete until a few seconds later.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I may be wrong, but it seems like your `sleep` needs to be asynchronous? Look into https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#sleeping

Comment: Just a quick question/tip: Have you tried to use `asyncio.sleep()`? `time.sleep` is not really useful and outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time.sleep` is blocking, meaning that **all code execution** is stopped until the 5 seconds pass. Instead, use `asyncio.sleep`:

```py
from asyncio import sleep

def my_func():
  # code blah blah...
  await sleep(5)
  # code...
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `time.sleep(5)` to `await asyncio.sleep(5)` instead. While using `time.sleep` your entire code is frozen.

**Your code works like this:**

1. Sends your first message
2. Immediately "sleeps" for 5 seconds (because of `time.sleep(5)`)
3. After 5 seconds code resumes:

   - sends your second message
   - starts 5 second counter you used in `delete_after=5`

That's why it waits 10 seconds before deleting the message instead of the 5 you wanted. It just starts counter execution for `delete_after=5` later, because your `time.sleep` froze the whole code.

***Remember to `import asyncio` to use `asyncio.sleep`.***

Answer (score 1):

`await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=5)` use `asyncio.sleep` function to wait before deleting the message.

You use blocking call: `time.sleep(5)`. It blocks all your code and also blocks `await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=5)` timer execution.

You should use `asyncio.sleep`:

```py
import asyncio


@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
  with open('test.json', 'r') as homeworkfile:
    homework = json.loads(homeworkfile.read())
  embed=discord.Embed(title='Test', description=f"Here's the saved contents for test: {homework}", color=0x9932CC)
  deletewarn=discord.Embed(title='Answer ticket expired.', description="Oops, looks like this ticket expired. Try saying !ss again?", color=0x9932CC)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=5)
  await asyncio.sleep(5)
  await ctx.send(embed=deletewarn)
```